# Accessing values declared in a PHP parent document in an included file called by a require statement *inside* a generic function

Tags: php, function, require

This is something of a clean coding question.

After declaring some variables in a parent document, and a `require` statement:

```
$My_Variable = 'Something here';
$My_Variable_2 = 'Something else here';

require __DIR__.'/test2.php'; // More stuff will happen to $My_Variable and $My_Variable_2 here...
```

instead of a raw require statement, I'd like to invoke a clean-syntax function which executes the `require` statement:

```
Require_Script($Arguments);
```

where the `Require_Script()` function looks something like this:

```
function Require_Script($Arguments) {

  // Some other code here;

  require __DIR__.'/test2.php';
}
```

I note that, ***unless I'm careful***, the variables declared in the parent document (which could be different variables in different contexts) which were going to be manipulated in `test2.php` (and which *were* available to that `include` when I used the raw `require` statement) are no longer available in `test2.php` - presumably because the `require` statement is now in a different scope.

---

Here's what it looks like in practice. Here are a couple of includes:

**test2.php :**

```
$My_Variable .= ' which has been upgraded';
$My_Variable_2 .= ' which has also been upgraded';
```

**test3.php :**

```
$My_Variable .= ' not once but twice.';
$My_Variable_2 .= ' also not just once but twice.';
```

And here's the **Parent Document**:

```
$My_Variable = 'This is my variable';
$My_Variable_2 = 'This is my other variable';

echo '<p>'.$My_Variable.'</p>'; // This is my variable
echo '<p>'.$My_Variable_2.'</p>'; // This is my other variable

***********
***********

require __DIR__.'/test2.php';

echo '<p>'.$My_Variable.'</p>'; // This is my variable which has been upgraded
echo '<p>'.$My_Variable_2.'</p>'; // This is my other variable which has also been upgraded

***********
***********

function My_Require_Function($logicVariables) {

  foreach ($logicVariables as $key => $value) {

    ${$key} = $value;

    global ${$key};
  }

  require __DIR__.'/test3.php';
}


My_Require_Function(['My_Variable' => $My_Variable, 'My_Variable_2' => $My_Variable_2]);

echo '<p>'.$My_Variable.'</p>'; // This is my variable which has been upgraded not once but twice.
echo '<p>'.$My_Variable_2.'</p>'; // This is my other variable which has also been upgraded also not just once but twice.
```

So, it works. But surely there must be better approaches?

This approach uses:

- an over-elaborate associative array parameter
- a custom equivalent of `extract()`
- variable variables
- (worst of all) `global`

---

My question is:

What (much) better alternative approaches exist to enable me to syntactically replace

```
require __DIR__.'/test2.php'
```

with a function which incorporates a require statement and looks something like:

```
Require_Script($Arguments)
```

Comment: If you're trying to code cleanly, don't make so much use of global variables in the first place. The include file should define functions, which you call in the parent script, and pass the variables as parameters.

Comment: You may find [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) a better platform for your question.

Comment: Your best bet is to treat your PHP "requires()" and "include()" as you would a [C/C++ header file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html).  *ONLY* put in declarations and definitions that you need to share among different modules.  Do *NOT* put in any code that actually "changes stuff"!  Yes, "globals" can be "Bad".  But misusing requires (if I'm understanding you correctly) is also "Bad".  What you're doing in test2.php and test3.php is "Evil" :(

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - yes, I don't want to use `global` at all. The parent document is an `included` file and these variables are not global variables.

Comment: Then why are you writing include files that use variables that are assigned in the parent script?

Comment: Any variable that's defined in the parent script and used in the include file is like a global variable.

Comment: Thanks @jibsteroos, I was unaware of [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I'll do some reading and seriously consider signing up.

Comment: To answer questions from both Barmar and @paulsm4 - the purpose of the sub-include here is to remove optional / arbitrary code from the parent include, so that it may be included or not.

Answer (score 1):

I really liked @Barmar's observation in the comments above that:

> The include file should define functions, which you call in the parent
>   script, and pass the variables as parameters.

So I set about thinking of an approach which, rather than simply `including` some lines of code to  modify variables from the parent document, would, instead, `include` and then run a `function` instead.

This would require 4 steps:

1. a function in the parent document which accepts as parameters both the name of the function to be included *and* an associative array containing the argument values that will be fed to that remote function
2. the remote function (in the `included` file) to `extract()` all variables from the submitted associative array
3. the remote function (in the `included` file) to process all those variables and then re-build its own associative array and return that
4. the parent document to `extract()` all variables from the returned associative array

This ended up looking like this:

**test4.php**

```
function test4($logicVariables) {

  extract($logicVariables);

  $My_Variable .= ' not once but twice.';
  $My_Variable_2 .= ' also not just once but twice.';

  return ['My_Variable' => $My_Variable, 'My_Variable_2' => $My_Variable_2];
}
```

**Parent Document:**

```
function My_New_Require_Function($Include_Name, $logicVariables) {

  require __DIR__.'/'.$Include_Name.'.php';

  return $Include_Name($logicVariables);
}

$My_Variables = ['My_Variable' => $My_Variable, 'My_Variable_2' => $My_Variable_2];
$My_Variables = My_New_Require_Function('test4', $My_Variables);
extract($My_Variables);
```

In a nutshell this process follows these **7 steps**:

- Package up variables in Parent Document **=>**
- Submit package of variables to function **=>**
- Unpackage variables inside function **=>**
- Process variables **=>**
- Repackage up processed variables **=>**
- Return Package to Parent Document **=>**
- Unpackage processed variables

The really good news is that *this approach works* and it **doesn't** require a custom equivalent of `extract()` or variable variables or `global`. (Though it does still require an associative array to be submitted to the function.)

Finally I saw that if the associative array had only one entry (or relatively few entries) I could make the last three lines a lot more concise, by simply rewriting as a single line:

```
extract(My_New_Require_Function('test4', ['My_Variable' => $My_Variable]));
```

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding how any of this could possibly be a good idea for any conceivable use case,  *WHY*?  Also: Q: Who is Rounin, and why is he calling himself Monica?  Just curious...

Comment: **Rounin** is my username. [**Monica**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology/334269#334269) is an SE Mod who was [sacked without warning or accountability by Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335508/monicas-situation-continues-unresolved-is-se-hoping-the-problem-just-goes-away). (See dozens of Meta SE threads). _"Je suis Monica"_ is a nod to [_"Je suis Charlie"_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Je_suis_Charlie), a call for free speech from 2015. SE users have adopted _Reinstate Monica_ and other calls for due process.

Comment: To answer your first question, I am designing a CMS which utilises user-written modules. The modules have a standard format and must be able to incorporate different components using a standardised syntax to include those components. Many modules simply pull in _Data components_ (or other Modules) and then deliver output. Some modules need an additional _Logic Component_ to process the _Data Components_. What I have been working on above is how to externalise the _Logic Component_ so that it can be (optionally) required by the Module.

Comment: Got it.  I strongly urge you to consider looking at ["classes" and/or "interfaces":](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-interface/).  But you obviously know most about the problem, so I'm confident in your ability to choose the"right tool". If you edit your post to clarify why your solution is "better" - I'd be happy to upvote it.  ALSO: I read about the "Monica" issue, and I agree.  I would have understood "I'm with Monica" ... I just never make the connection to "Je suis Charlie".  Thank you for clarifying :)

Comment: Sorry, you stated: _If you edit your post to clarify why your solution is "better"_. I am happy to make edits to the answer above, but... better than what?

Comment: 1) Main issue: SO won't let me retract my vote unless the post is edited.  2) Even though I now get - and respect - that you have a good reason for doing what you're doing ... I still don't completely understand your use case ... or how doing a bunch of includes and extracts and whatever else could *POSSIBLY* make more sense than simply defining a "class" (in it's own PHP file), extending it as needed, and having the caller instantiate one class or another.  Or combining "classes" and "interfaces".  I'm not saying you're "wrong" - I just don't get it :(

Comment: To use a "C" analogy: it sounds a bit like you're trying to re-invent [CFront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront) ... instead of just coding in C++.

Comment: No, it's okay, I massively appreciate your input and feedback, @paulsm4 (and Barmar's too). Don't over-estimate my familiarity with PHP control structures. I've only been scripting in PHP since 2012, before which time I couldn't have told you what an `array` was. I only used my first `associative array` in 2016. Since 2016, I've mostly been scripting in Javascript (ES5 until a year ago and now, ever increasingly, ES2015+). So I'm still quite daunted by PHP `objects` and `classes`. That said, this might turn out to be my best opportunity yet to learn and become familiar with deploying them.

Comment: The other consideration I have is my audience. I am architecting for a userbase who have an interest in building their own custom (and customised) modules, but a good proportion of them will want to use pre-written components and bolt them on to each other (like lego). So the modules/components all need to be able to present themselves using the same (fairly strict) structure. Regard the users as being a few degrees more technical than the average non-technical Wordpress user. ie. Not a complete neophyte... someone who knows HTML and CSS but probably not very much Javascript or PHP.